# Select data: paginating data from multiple tables with inconsistent dates

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I have 8 separate tables. Each table has id, a datetime field and some text.

I am presenting data combined from all tables on a single page in a timeline view, most recent entries are at the top, and entries from each table are mixed in this timeline.

Now the hard part - I need to add pagination to this website, so on each page I want to show exactly 10 days (except for the last page, that may have less than 10).
Each table may have variable number of rows.

I've been struggling with this for quite some time but have not yet come up with an elegant solution.

Here's an example (I'll pick only two tables for this example to make it simpler).

### tableA

Apr 1 | a1
Apr 5 | a2
Apr 7 | a3

### tableB

Apr 2 | b1
Apr 2 | b2
Apr 5 | b3
Apr 6 | b4

Global timeline would look like this

---

Apr 7 a3
Apr 6 b4
Apr 5 a2
Apr 5 b3
Apr 2 b2
Apr 2 b1
Apr 1 a1

And if each page shows only 3 days, I need for it to look like this:

--- p1 ---
Apr 7 a3
Apr 6 b4
Apr 5 a2

--- p2 ---
Apr 5 b3
Apr 2 b2
Apr 2 b1

--- p3 ---
Apr 1 a1

The problem is - I can't figure out a way to query for this data in an elegant way. Here's some live query that I've been messing with:

select date(d.entryTime) entryDate, date(wc.changeTime) wcDate
from diary_entry d
join water_change wc
on d.aquariumId = wc.aquariumId
where d.aquariumId = 2
group by entryDate
order by entryDate
limit 10, 5

so, for one table I have this query:
select date(d.entryTime) entryDate
from diary_entry d
where d.aquariumId = 2
group by entryDate

it yields 13 results
entryDate
2012-01-13
2012-01-14
2012-01-25
2012-01-26
2012-01-31
2012-02-04
2012-02-17
2012-02-20
2012-02-25
2012-03-17
2012-03-31
2012-04-01
2012-04-06

and for another:
select date(wc.changeTime) changeDate
from water_change wc
where wc.aquariumId = 2
group by changeTime

it yields 8 results
2012-01-22
2012-01-26
2012-02-17
2012-02-25
2012-03-04
2012-03-10
2012-04-04
2012-04-24

There are three common days between the two
2012-01-26
2012-02-17
2012-02-25

So the query that I need to produce would have to have
13 + 8 - 3 rows = 18 rows

And solution is found!
(select date(d.entryTime) activityDate
from diary_entry d
where d.aquariumId = 1
group by activityDate)
union
(select date(wc.changeTime) activityDate
from water_change wc
where wc.aquariumId = 1
group by activityDate
order by activityDate)
limit 10, 10

Comment: Define your problem. Is the problem making the query?  Getting the data to the front end? Paginating?  I don't know where to begin to help you.

Comment: Just edited the original question with an example and some extra notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query it using a Union.

```
SELECT TheDate,
       TheText
  FROM Table_A
 WHERE [your critera]
 UNION
SELECT TheDate,
       TheText
  FROM Table_B
 WHERE [your critera]
...
```

If you need to only select the distinct ones, you can then wrap this as follows:

```
Select Distinct
       TheDate,
       TheText
  From 
(
 SELECT TheDate,
       TheText
  FROM Table_A
 WHERE [your critera]
 UNION
SELECT TheDate,
       TheText
  FROM Table_B
 WHERE [your critera]
...
);
```

Comment: I used:select date(d.entryTime) activityDate
from diary_entry d
where d.aquariumId = 2
group by activityDate
union
select date(wc.changeTime) activityDate
from water_change wc
where wc.aquariumId = 2
group by activityDate
order by activityDate  and it works! Now I just need to apply limits to it. This is incredible!

Comment: @tumanov, okay... did that work?  And what "limits" do you need to apply?

Comment: @tumanov, I'm glad that worked for you. Please accept this as the solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: As for your distinct comment, I believe that if in my case (query is posted in the original question) it already takes care of duplicates.

Comment: Not to beat the dead horse, but should not I be using group by, in order to group multiple date times into a single date?

Comment: @tumanov, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  `distinct` will give you unique rows. `Group by` is typically used when you're doing a collection function like `COUNT` where your DB needs to figure out which numbers get counted as part of a specific label.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got the select and joins in place and are just missing the pageination.  If that's the case, your script will have to keep track of what page you're on, and each click on "next page" will have to tell MySQL where to return the next 10 records from by appending this to your SELECT query:

*SELECT...JOIN...WHERE...ORDER BY*...**LIMIT 20, 10**

Will return the next 10 rows beginning with the 21st row in the full record set

Comment: It is actually the selects and joins that I am missing as well. For example, how do I combine two separate date columns, does it have to be a regular join? Now if I have 8 tables, would not that be a little too much? And the grouping is probably going to be off.

Comment: I just tried this query with a set and it looks like I can not do that, the syntax is not correct: select date(d.entryTime) activityDate
from diary_entry d
where d.aquariumId = 1
group by activityDate
union
select date(wc.changeTime) activityDate
from water_change wc
where wc.aquariumId = 1
group by activityDate
order by activityDate
limit 10, 10

Comment: Please never mind, this is just me not rtfming, I needed parenthesis

Comment: np....fresh eyes is what makes those things stand out, though that has certainly NEVER happened to me (lol)